# Accessing TCL libraries

Tags: tcl, tclsh

I am new to TCL and am struggling with accessing other modules.  The SOURCE command helped me include other code that I have written in a TCL program.  However, I think I have a problem with accessing libraries of code.

For example, when I reference a math function, it is not found.  I think there must be something I need to do to include where the math library is on my computer in the search for a program called via tchsh85.

```
invalid command name "::math::statistics::mv-ols"
```

None of these directories exist on my computer:

```
info library= C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5
auto_path= C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5 C:/Tcl/lib c:/tcl/lib/teapot/package/win32-x86_64/lib               c:/tcl/lib/teapot/package/tcl/lib
tcl library= C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/word.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/tm.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/tm.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/parray.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/history.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/history.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/package.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/history.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/word.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/word.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/package.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/tm.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/auto.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/auto.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/auto.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/auto.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/auto.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/history.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/auto.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/history.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/package.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/auto.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/auto.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/history.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/tm.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/auto.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/auto.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/word.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/package.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/auto.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/history.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/package.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/word.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/history.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/auto.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/history.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/tm.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/tm.tcl
auto_index= source C:/Tcl/lib/tcl8.5/safe.tcl
```

Answer (score 2):

The command that you want to succeed is:

```
package require math::statistics
```

You're not supposed to get the code by other ways (like a direct `source`) because you're then binding to the *implementation* of the package instead of the *specification* of it. That package is a part of the Tcllib collection, which you should install somewhere on your computer.

If you're using ActiveTcl, you want to do:

```
teacup update
```

That will install *many* packages and set up all the paths you require.

If you're using your own build, you'll have to download a copy of Tcllib for yourself and follow its installation instructions. I can't remember where it installs to by default on Window, but let's say it is to `C:\Tcl\lib\Tcllib` (with the actual packages in subdirectories of that): in that case you'd make the packages available to Tcl by doing:

```
lappend auto_path C:/Tcl/lib/Tcllib
```

<sup>If you're making a redistributable executable, there's additional techniques. Ask another question in that case.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

::math::statistics is part of TCLlib. To check if you have it installed, type

```
package require tcllib
```

and if it is installed, it will tell you the version number. If it's not installed, you can use [Teacup](http://wiki.tcl.tk/17305) to install it for you.